# W3 total - leverage browser caching not working with cdn delivered images

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, cdn

I'm using W3 total cache for a while now with all my Wordpress installations. Just started to use CDN and I got some problems with **leverage browser caching** of my files (mostly images) that are served from my CDN. W3 total won't cache those files and I think because they are on a CDN.

I'm getting this message with Pingdom:

**The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:**

All files served from my CDN.

Is this a known issue or is it just me with this problem and doing something wrong?

Comment: What CDN do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Your expires value in your CDN settings is likely set to a low number. Your CDN expires header is overriding what is coming from your origin server which is why when you enabled the CDN, you received that message from Pingdom. Try increasing your CDN's expires value.

Also if you're searching for a reliable CDN service I would recommend giving [KeyCDN](https://www.keycdn.com/) a try.